# VBA worksheet change code running multiple times

Tags: vba, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have this code in place to basically evaluate the entry in a range of cells, and to check to see if it conforms to a pattern of [1-9], and if so do a vlookup of a small table which has 2 columns (1-9 as the index, then in column 2 the description of what these values mean). My code is :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim tgt As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Object
'Dim yn As Boolean

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set rng1 = ws.Range("K13:K" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng1) Is Nothing Then

       If Target.Value Like "[1-9]*" Then

       'MsgBox "OK" & Target.Address & " " & Target.Text & " " & rng1.Address & " " & rng1.Count & " " & ActiveCell.Address

        Target.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Left(Target.Value, 1), ws.Range("J2:K10"), 2, 0)

        ElseIf Not Target Like "[1-9*]" Then

       Target = Empty

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

The problem I am getting is that the code runs fine, but it is evaluated multiple times (like 40-50 times), after each cell change event. I put a msgbox there to maybe understand what is happening but I'm stuck and don't know how to fix the code. I'm thinking it has to do with the VLOOKUP function.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Target.Value = ...
> ```

will invoke `Worksheet_Change` once again and again. Solution: *diasble events*. This is the correct solution to avoid a *re-entrant* event handler:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  On Error Goto Cleanup

 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 '
 ' Your initital code goes here
 '
 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Cleanup:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Importantly, if your initial code ever has an `Exit Sub` statement, replace it with `Goto Cleanup`. this is important because you surely **want** to enable events again so your application keeps working correctly.